# how to make an array of files which are part of a .zip file

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, zip

i am trying to make an array of files which are part of a .zip file.
In the .zip file are 2 files: `image1.jpg` and `image2.jpg`

```
$zip = new ZipArchive;
        if ($zip->open($_POST['extractfile']) === TRUE) {

            $unzipped = 0; 
            $fails = 0; 
            $total = 0; 
            for ($i = 0; $i < $zip->numFiles; $i++) {
                $path_info = pathinfo($zip->getNameIndex($i));
                $ext = $path_info['extension'];
                $total ++; 

                echo $zip->getNameIndex($i);
```

The echo outputs only the first file: `image1.jpg`

How can i make an array of the files which are in the `.zip` file so that i can use a foreach loop like below:

```
foreach($extractfiles as $extractfile) {
     echo $extractfile;
}
```

Comment: put before for loop this code: `echo "Files in ZIP: $zip->numFiles <br>" . PHP_EOL;` and after `echo $zip->getNameIndex($i);` put line `echo "Iteration Number: $i <br>" . PHP_EOL;` You should see `Files in ZIP: 2` and `Iteration Number: 0` and `Iteration Number: 1`. If files in Zip is 1 then there is one file in your zip (check path to file). if you don't see `Iteration Number: 1` then your loop is interrupted after the line `echo $zip->getNameIndex($i);` because of an error that you don't see.

Comment: I agree, my loop was interrupted! There was another if statement in the loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To the second part

```
<?php

$zip = new ZipArchive;

        $extractfiles = [];

        if ($zip->open($_POST['extractfile']) === TRUE) {


            $unzipped = 0; 
            $fails = 0; 
            $total = 0; 
            for ($i = 0; $i < $zip->numFiles; $i++) {
                $path_info = pathinfo($zip->getNameIndex($i));
                $ext = $path_info['extension'];
                $total ++; 

                echo $zip->getNameIndex($i);

                $extractfiles[] = $zip->getNameIndex($i);

            }

        }


foreach($extractfiles as $extractfile) {
     echo $extractfile . "<br>" . PHP_EOL;
}
```